# gnuplot experiencing overflow?

Tags: overflow, gnuplot

I'm trying to plot certain data created with fortran and I find that gnuplot simply ignores part of my data.

After double- and triple-checking I had gotten all the I/O right and gnuplot could read the data I was creating, I came to realize that gnuplot doesn't accept observations greater or equal (in absolute value) than 1.0E308.

I don't think it's an issue with my machine, as fortran is creating this data without complaining.

Therefore, my question is whether there's a way within gnuplot to figure out what the largest number it'll handle is and whether that limit is adjustable in any way. I couldn't find anything of the sorts in the documentation.

Comment: Yes, that the limit of a 64bit double. But why do you need such large values?

Comment: If that's the largest value the machine can handle, why can fortran handle them?I use these huge values to make sure certain areas of the state space within an optimization model are never chosen.

Comment: How do you set those values in your program?

Comment: Fortran has a built-in function called huge(x), which gives you the largest (in absolute value) value it can handle.

Comment: Ok, but of what type is `x` and which compiler do you use? (I'm not sure, if Fortran may have compiler-dependent behavior to use doubles with more then 64bit). And, how are the data points exactly written out to your data file (`1D+400`, `1E400`)?

Comment: In my data file, they're written as -1.00000000E308. x is of type double, whereas the exact precision (I use the NAG library working precision, which is machine dependent) I can't determine right now because I don't have access to the machine until next week.